# How to check if the table is displayed before calling a function creating the table - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am a new coder. I created a simple app that will parse user's input data and display it in a table.
The user flow would be as follows:

1. from the drop down menu, they choose a message to work with ( 1 Log in or 2 Log out)
2. Into the Request or Response field they enter their data that looks like this: 1,2,3,4,5
3. Press Parse and see their data displayed in a table.
   My problem here is, if the user presses Parse button more than once, the tables keep building up. How do I modify my code to check if a table is already displayed and, if it is, to delete/hide it before running the code that creates the table? Please, help!

Here's the code snippet:

```js
function goToNewPage(src){
    window.location = src;
}

realArrayRequest = [];
realArrayResponse = [];

function generateTableRequest(){

    var tbl = document.createElement("table");
    var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
    //var input = parseUserInputReq();


    for(var i=0; i<realArrayRequest.length; i++){ //rows
        var row=document.createElement("tr");

        for (var j=0; j < 3; j++){
            if (j === 0){  //columns
                if(getDropDownValue() === "1 Log In"){ 
                    var cell = document.createElement("td");
                    var cellText = document.createTextNode(msg1Req[i]);
                    cell.appendChild(cellText);
                    row.appendChild(cell);
                } else if (getDropDownValue() === "2 Log Out"){ 
                    var cell = document.createElement("td");
                    var cellText = document.createTextNode(msg2Req[i]);
                    cell.appendChild(cellText);
                    row.appendChild(cell);
                };
            } else if (j === 1){
                var cell = document.createElement("td");
                var cellText = document.createTextNode(realArrayRequest[i]);
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);
            } else if (j === 2){
                if (getDropDownValue() === "1 Log In"){
                    var cell = document.createElement("td");
                    var cellText = document.createTextNode(msg1ReqType[i]);
                    cell.appendChild(cellText);
                    row.appendChild(cell);
                } else if (getDropDownValue() === "2 Log Out"){
                    var cell = document.createElement("td");
                    var cellText = document.createTextNode(msg2ReqType[i]);
                    cell.appendChild(cellText);
                    row.appendChild(cell);
                } 
    }
            
     tblBody.appendChild(row);
    }

    tbl.appendChild(tblBody);

    var parseCommandRequestDiv = document.getElementById("parseCommandRequest");
    parseCommandRequestDiv.appendChild(tbl);     
    tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
}
}



function generateTableResponse(){
    var body = document.body;
    var tbl = document.createElement("table");
    var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

    for(var i=0; i<realArrayResponse.length; i++){ //rows
        var row=document.createElement("tr");

        for (var j=0; j < 3; j++){
            if (j === 0){  //columns
                
                if(getDropDownValue() === "1 Log In"){ 
                    var cell = document.createElement("td");
                    var cellText = document.createTextNode(msg1Res[i]);
                    cell.appendChild(cellText);
                    row.appendChild(cell);
                } else if (getDropDownValue() === "2 Log Out"){
                    var cell = document.createElement("td");
                    var cellText = document.createTextNode(msg2Res[i]);
                    cell.appendChild(cellText);
                    row.appendChild(cell);
                }
            } else if (j === 1){
                var cell = document.createElement("td");
                var cellText = document.createTextNode(realArrayResponse[i]);
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);
            } else if (j === 2){
                if (getDropDownValue() === "1 Log In"){
                    var cell = document.createElement("td");
                    var cellText = document.createTextNode(msg1ResType[i]);
                    cell.appendChild(cellText);
                    row.appendChild(cell);
                } else {
                    var cell = document.createElement("td");
                    var cellText = document.createTextNode(msg2ResType[i]);
                    cell.appendChild(cellText);
                    row.appendChild(cell)
                    };
            } else {  
                var cell = document.createElement("td");
                var cellText = document.createTextNode('');
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);
        } 
            
        }
     tblBody.appendChild(row);
    }
    tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
    var parseCommandResponseDiv = document.getElementById("parseCommandResponse");
    parseCommandResponseDiv.appendChild(tbl); 
    tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
}


 function getDropDownValue (){ //getting the text from the drop down menu
    var selectElement = document.getElementById("dropDownMessageMenu");
    var selectValue = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].text;
    return selectValue;
};


function parseUserInputReq(){
    realArrayRequest=[]; 
    
    var input = document.getElementById("userInputRequest").value;
    var noBracketsStr=input.split(",");

        for(var i = 0; i < noBracketsStr.length; i++){
            realArrayRequest.push(noBracketsStr[i])
        }
  
    generateTableRequest();
}

function parseUserInputRes(){
    realArrayResponse=[]; 
    var input = document.getElementById("userInputResponse").value;
    var noBracketsStr=input.split(",");

        for(var i = 0; i < noBracketsStr.length; i++){
            realArrayResponse.push(noBracketsStr[i])
        }
  
    generateTableResponse();
}






//Message elements

//Message 1
const msg1Req = ['Login Command', 'version', 'xID', 'passcode', 'machineID', 'equipment Serial Number', 'userSlot', 'clubID', 'loginType'];
const msg1ReqType = ['integer', 'integer', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'integer', 'integer', 'string'];
const msg1Res = ['Login Command', 'Version', 'Result', 'User token'];
const msg1ResType = ['integer', 'integer', 'integer', 'string'];
//Message 2
const msg2Req = ['Logout Command', 'Version', 'User Token', 'Machine ID'];
const msg2ReqType = ['integer', 'integer', 'string', 'string'];
const msg2Res = ['Logout Command', 'Version', 'Result', 'Error message on failure'];
const msg2ResType = ['Integer', 'Integer', 'Integer', 'string']
```

```css
#parseCommandRequest {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
};

#parseCommandResponse {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script defer type="text/javascript" src="index.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <br><br>
    <div>
        Select a message you want to parse
        <select name="dropDownMessageMenu" id="dropDownMessageMenu">
            <option value="msg0" disabled selected></option>
            <option value="msg1">1 Log In</option>
            <option value="msg2">2 Log Out</option>
           
        </select> <br> <br>
    </div>
    <div id="parseCommandRequest">
        <form name="userInputReq">
            Request 
            <input type="text" id="userInputRequest"> 
            <input type="button" value="Parse" onclick="parseUserInputReq()">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="parseCommandResponse">
        <form name="userInputRes">
            Response 
            <input type="text" id="userInputResponse"> 
            <input type="button" value="Parse" onclick="parseUserInputRes()">
        </form>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What should happen if the table is displayed and the user now changes the input and clicks parse. Should it add another row ? Or will the table never contain more than 1 row.

Comment: @VipulTawde, then a new table should be created, filled with data from the new user input. Ideally, the old table should be deleted before that.

Comment: so the table will always have max 1 row right?

Comment: @VipulTawde, no, the number of rows will depend on how many comma delimited elements there are in user's entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello :) If you want to check if your table has been created already, you can just request it in dom and check is presence:

```
if(document.querySelector('table'))
{
   //my table exists
}
```

if `document.querySelector('table')` exists, it will return the element, if it doesn't it will return null

Comment: How would I implement this in my code?
    if(document.querySelector(tbl) != null){
        tbl.remove()
    } else { // create the table} ?

Comment: This solution worked for me. I ended up using this code to check if the table exists and added document.querySelector('table').remove() to delete the table. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could create the table with an id and check if the table is already created. If the table is already created you need to insert the rows into the already existing table.